# Is Visual Studio 2010 compatible with Windows 7 Home Basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is Visual Studio 2010 compatible with Windows 7 Home Basic? I'd be using SQL Server that comes with VS 2010 also. Are there any issues in the installation on Windows 7 Home Basic?

Answer (score 2):

100% compatible, no need to worry about any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a list of supported Operating Systems for Visual Studio 2010. Since it specifies that the starter edition is not compatible for Vista SP2, and does not make that exception for Windows 7, you can be confident that they are compatible.

**System Requirements**
Supported Operating Systems:

- Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
- Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
- WindowsServer 2003 R2 (x86 and x64) - all editions
- Windows Server 2008 (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64) all editions

Supported Architectures:

- 32-Bit (x86)
- 64-Bit (x64) (WOW)

Comment: Is there a link available for that to MSDN?